# Can i find request type in ActionExecutingContext object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to identify if request is ajax based or simple request from ActionExecutingContext object. Is this possible to identify? Im using C# and Asp.Net MVC 2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()`. The [IsAjaxRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest.aspx) is an extension method of the [HttpRequestBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.aspx) class.